# Docker for Windows Beta + Docker Tools for Visual Studio -- DockerTask.ps1 Error

Tags: visual-studio, docker

I'm running the Docker for Windows Beta on Windows 10 Pro 10586. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm using Visual Studio Tools for Docker version 0.21.0.

I have played around with Docker in PowerShell, I've run the `hello-world` Docker image successfully.

I created an empty (hello world) .net Core RC2 asp.net app. I ran the app fine on IIS Express. Then I added Docker support to the project using Docker Tools for Visual Studio. Then I attempted to build and run the app in a Docker container. However I keep getting the following error -

`Failed to run the command: "C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\MVCAppExplorations\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\DockerTask.ps1 -Run -Environment Debug -Machine '' -OpenSite $False -RemoteDebugging $True".`

I have seen another post about a similar error. In that case the error was more like -

`Failed to run the command: "C:\Users\Duncan\Desktop\MVCAppExplorations\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\DockerTask.ps1 -Run -Environment Debug -Machine 'default' -OpenSite $False -RemoteDebugging $True".`

Notice the empty pair of single quotes in my error. When using Docker Tools for Visual Studio with Docker for Windows Beta a line is supposed to be edited in the `Docker.props` file (which is added to the Visual Studio project by the Docker Tools for Visual Studio). The line is -

`<DockerMachineName Condition=" '$(DockerMachineName)'=='' ">default</DockerMachineName>`

If running Docker for Windows Beta the line the comments in the `Docker.props` instructs to remove `default` changing the line to -

`<DockerMachineName Condition=" '$(DockerMachineName)'=='' "></DockerMachineName>`

In the other post about the similar error, the developer was getting the error because they had not amended this line and were trying to run their app with Docker for Windows Beta. However I have amended this line, I believe as instructed, but am getting a very similar error, just with a blank `''` machine name instead of `default`. I have also restarted Visual Studio as instructed in the `Docker.props` comments and even restarted my machine but I still get the error.

I appreciate Docker for Windows is Beta software, so is Docker Tools for Visual Studio, so this could just be a beta bug. However I'm interested to know if there is a solution to this issue. Help delving deeper into the issue to gain a better understanding would also be appreciated if there isn't a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use port 80 in your templates? Check with `netstat -a -b` if port 80 is already listened by another process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this issue is no longer relevant to me. Since posting the question I have upgraded to Redstone 1, Docker Tools for Visual Studio has had significant new versions released and Docker for Windows is now GA. I now have Docker and Docker Tools for Visual Studio working just fine. I did however experience a similar error getting it working which turned out to be related to not having volume mounting configured in Docker for Windows.